# Set Datetime in C# based on Timezone like +08:00

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timezone

I have created current date time like this.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Now I want to convert this to different time zone. But I am getting values in timezone like +05:30, +07:00 etc..

So how can I convert this now value to that specific timezone date using this kind of timezone value.

Thanks

Comment: @YongShun I tried this way, DateTimeOffset d = new DateTimeOffset(now, new TimeSpan(+5, 0, 0)); -- but getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [DateTimeOffset.ToOffset(TimeSpan)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tooffset?view=netframework-4.8) to convert Utc to your desired timezone.

```cs
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTimeOffset dtoUtc = new DateTimeOffset(now);
TimeSpan offset = new TimeSpan(+5, 00, 00);  // Specify timezone
var dtToSpecificTimezone = dtoUtc.ToOffset(offset);

Console.WriteLine(dtToSpecificTimezone.ToString());
```

Output:

> 7/11/2021 3:02:10 PM +05:00

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYKYek)